# Change li style for a range of specific links

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

Is there any way to change the image I use for a specific set of `<li>` items?

My code currently is:

```
#huisaankopen ul li{
    background:url('/apps/website/view/img/icon_arrow_right_green.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 6px;
}
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Basically I want these li items to have a different image to appear infront of every <li>'d item. different from the rest of my website.

Comment: I can't connect with your website. Could you attach HTML from your website? Is this any unique selector on this list ?

Comment: If you mean the bullet then yes by adjusting the `list-style-type` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: Give this list an ID or class, then target it specifically so your other lists don't get the styling applied to them.

Comment: Thanks! Gave it a class, works like a charm! Much appreciated.